# Setting a larger size for BytesColumnVector

Tags: scala, hive

BytesColumnVector has two constructors:

```
public BytesColumnVector() {
    this(1024);
}

public BytesColumnVector(int size) {
    super(Type.BYTES, size);
    this.vector = new byte[size][];
    this.start = new int[size];
    this.length = new int[size];
}
```

And this is how we use it in our code:

```
val key = m.keys
           .asInstanceOf[BytesColumnVector]
           .toString(index.toInt)
```

Question is, how can I use the second constructor which accepts a "size" input? Thanks!